# MongoDB: search in object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection with next items (example one item)

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b2cb384ee93081e2b2b1ffd"),
    "publishedItems": {
        "0a4ec2faf5b08ece993a7949739b9727": {"id":"1234"},
        "0a4ec2faf5b08ece993a79497391234": {"id":4567},
        "12332faf5b08ece993a7949739b9727": {"id":"7890"},
},
    "currentContentKey": "0a4ec2faf5b08ece993a7949739b9727",
    "draft": {}
}
```

I want to get this item by id inside publishedItems
I use next query

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
{
   $project:{
       "_id":1,
       currentContentKey:1,
       published:"$publishedItems"
   }
},
{
   $match:{
       $or:[
           {
               "published.currentContentKey.id":"1234"
           }
       ]
   }
}
])
```

Is it possible use **currentContentKey** from $project inside dot notation query? Is it possible to create one query to get item by id from publishedItems?

**Update**

Thanks @AlexBlex

My final query is:

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
{
   $project:{
       "_id":1,
       currentContentKey:1,
       published: "$publishedItems",
       pub:{$objectToArray:"$publishedItems"}
   }
},
{
   $match:{
       $or:[
           {
               "pub":{$elemMatch:{"v.id": ObjectId("5b2cb3ca367df10631f1aac7")}}
           }
       ]
   }
}
])
```

Comment: @RahulSharma, Why so? Evgeniy, you can. Ya razreshayu =)

Comment: @AlexBlex I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's even better. You don't actually need $elemMatch. `{"pub.v.id": ObjectId("5b2cb3ca367df10631f1aac7")}` does the job.

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        currentPublished: { $arrayElemAt: [
            { $filter: { 
                input: { $objectToArray: "$publishedItems" }, 
                as: "one", 
                cond: { $eq: ["$$one.k", "$currentContentKey"]} 
            } },
            0
         ] }
    } },
    { $match: {
        $or:[
            {"currentPublished.v.id": "1234"}
        ]
    } }
    { $project: {
        "_id":1,
        currentContentKey:1,
        published:"$publishedItems"
    } },
])
```